# Пропадает svg при скроле

Tags: html, css, svg, fullpage

Подскажите пожалуйста. стоит плагин `fullpage`. на главном экране есть скос, которые сделан при помощи `svg`. Если листать дальше и вернутся обратно на первую то эта `svg` появится с задержкой. Тобшь мы попадаем на первую - не видим этот скос и через несколько секунд он появляется. При чем в самом `html` он есть, размеры у него есть, не скрывается. Пробовал делать этот угол `CSS`-ом, картинкой и всегда одно и тоже.

[тут можно посмотреть](http://sloyev.de/de) (не реклама)

Answer (score 0):

Это просто глюк Хрома. Я не до конца понял, что это, но это не связано с svg. Див со слайдшоу, который имеет `overflow:hidden` при прокрутке выезжает на передний план.  Если убрать  `overflow:hidden` бага не наблюдается. Так-же нет проблем в Firefox. Попробуйте поотключать неумесные `transform-3d`, может это связано с ними как-то.